# Git pull - deleted files

Tags: git, repository, pull

I have a development server and a couple of production ones. I do commits from the dev to a remote repository and have `git push production` setup, that issues a pull from the production servers.
I needed to remove a couple of directories with static files from being tracked so I did this

[Remove an Existing File from a Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124792/have-git-stop-tracking-a-file)
(summary: did `git rm --cached myfolders`, and after that added to .gitignore the folders)

I have not yet committed the changes. The files show as deleted when doing `git status`

```
#       deleted:    file1.jpg
#       deleted:    file2.jpg
#       deleted:    file3.jpg
#       deleted:    file4.jpg
#       deleted:    file5.jpg
```

My concern is: will the 'deleted' files be removed from production servers (from disk) when `git pull` is being performed? 
I just want them untracked, but not deleted from disk.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help thinking that managing a deployment to production in this way is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you. Don't know if you would consider it better that the pull is not really automatic, I do "git push production" from dev. Edited the question. I personally prefer a rsync script to do all that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if you pull a commit that includes deletions, the files will be deleted. You'll need to restore the files manually afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the files will be deleted if you do a `git pull`. Git couldn't do anything else - suppose some code in the repository depended on the existence or non-existence of some file. Removing a file might have a significant resulting behaviour, so Git must remove the file when pulling.

Comment: Thanks! Was about to do a big mistake in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

As the others answered, you need to restore the deleted files manually. You can do that with

```
git checkout sha1 -- file1.jpg file2.jpg
```

where `sha1` is the commit beofre the merge. There are multiple ways to get that one, like with `HEAD~1` or the easiest copy from the output from the pull. There is something like

> ```
> Updating bea26f6..d5a6bc6
> ```

where the first commit was the one you had localy before.