# Excluding certain files while 'git pull'

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore, git-track

I am doing a complex PHP project with two other people. We had git setup for the project from the beginning.  After working for two months, we wanted to remove certain folders (`/dev/app`) from git tracking ( git was already tracking them). So I deleted all the files from `/dev/app` and added a entry in the `.gitignore` file to exclude the `PHP` files in the `/dev/app` folder.

```
**/dev/app/*.php
```

I made a commit to the master branch. I pushed them to the origin and it was working fine. But my colleagues were working on different branches. When I merged their branches with the master, git started to track the excluded files again.

In the local environment it is not a problem, but in the production environment it is a huge headache.  I only need the client generated files in the /dev/app folder in the production server, and I need to preserve them without any modification.

can anyone help me to overcome the issue?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098586/git-pull-deleted-files

Comment: It is somewhat similar, but I am hoping to find out a way so that no one will be able to `push` those files in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You should add these files to .gitignore