# A locally ignored file was updated on remote; can't checkout to remote branch now

Tags: git, gitignore, git-checkout

Consider the following scenario:

I have the following in my `.gitignore`:

```
files/dependency/config.lua
```

But since the file used to exist before adding it to gitignore, it was being tracked. I updated my index and removed the file manually [following this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6317169/1190388). Now, one of my colleague updated this file on remote server.

When I try to checkout to remote branch, it shows:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>
> ```
> files/dependency/config.lua
> ```
>
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>
> Aborting

So, I read about it; and most of the answers I found tell you to use `git stash`. Since I don't have any changes made on local repository, I can not stash them.

I used the `--force` option to checkout, but it also returns with an error:

```
git checkout --force -B myBranch remote/branchname
error: Entry 'files/dependency/config.lua' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

Here, I'd paste my terminal:

```
┌─[hjpotter92:HEDWIG]─[fooDir]─[06:46 PM] (master u=)
└──$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
┌─[hjpotter92:HEDWIG]─[fooDir]─[06:39 PM] (master u=)
└──$ git checkout -b myBranch remote/branchname
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        files/dependency/config.lua
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
┌─[×]─[hjpotter92:HEDWIG]─[fooDir]─[06:39 PM] (master u=)
└──$ git stash
No local changes to save
┌─[hjpotter92:HEDWIG]─[fooDir]─[06:39 PM] (master u=)
└──$ git checkout -b myBranch remote/branchname
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        files/dependency/config.lua
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
┌─[×]─[hjpotter92:HEDWIG]─[fooDir]─[06:39 PM] (master u=)
└──$ git checkout --force -b myBranch remote/branchname
error: Entry 'files/dependency/config.lua' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

#### Question:

Is there some way to checkout the remote branch and then either force ignoring the file `files/dependency/config.lua` whenever someone pulls in my changes or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've currently made it work by indexing the ignored file once more. I used the command:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged files/dependency/config.lua
```

and then the `checkout` command executed easily and properly. I'll leave this as an answer here. If someone can answer the following question, I'd be grateful:

> Is there some way to checkout the remote branch and then either force
>   ignoring the file `files/dependency/config.lua` whenever someone pulls
>   in my changes or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Responding to your earlier question:

Check `git status` if it shows that `files/dependency/config.lua` is modified.

Then you need to follow these steps:

1. add file to `gitignore`. I think you already have this covered.
2. `git rm --cached files/dependency/config.lua`
3. `commit` this change.

Related: [Remove an Existing File from a Git Repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124792/remove-an-existing-file-from-a-git-repo)

Comment: My first command from the terminal was `git status`. You can see its output in the OP.

Comment: Ok, can you try step 2 & 3 that I suggested??